# Clojure - group by two values, count on specific key word

Tags: clojure, count, group-by

I have an xml file which I have read in and indexed on my editor. I have three status' by which they are denoted in the xml file - GOOD, AVERAGE, POOR; and they are also indexed by a date in DD/MM/YYYY format.

What I have to do is group them initially by month, so therefore stripping the month out of the date which I have successfully done and then loop through again and count the 'GOOD' status' on a per month basis.

I would assume that I would have to group by both Month and Status and then count the occurances of 'GOOD' although I seem to be getting stuck somewhere... what I have developed so far is below, hopefully I just need to tweak it slightly!

```
        ...data fed in from xml...
        data (doall (get-records (xml/parse is)))

        loopA (for [flop data]
        {
           :STATUS(:QUALITY_STATUS flop)
           :MONTH(get (split (:DATE flop)  #"/") 1)
        })

        x(group-by #(select-keys %[:MONTH :STATUS]) loopA)

        loopB (str-join \newline (for [floop x]
        {
            :MONTH_STAMP (second floop)
            :Q_STATUS (if (= :STATUS "GOOD") (second floop))
            :GOOD_QUAL (count :Q_STATUS)
        }))
```

Ideally what i want to end up with is three columns of data like the below:

Month -- Quality -- Count

01 -------      GOOD -----      1

02 -------      GOOD    -----   5

...

12 -------      GOOD   -----     3

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code block - it is difficult to read.

Comment: Can you provide a *short* xml sample?

Comment: Solved it - used a filter to get the GOOD Status out of the data - I'll post my code later